# What is the alloying composition of the Zinc-Platinum System?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, reference-request, metallurgy, alloy

My research team and I are working on a bimetallic alloy consisting of Zinc and Platinum. We have looked for papers regarding the composition of Zinc-Platinum alloy. But there aren't many papers out there.
So far, we have found only one paper:
Moser, Z. The Pt-Zn (Platinum-Zinc) system. *JPE* **1991,** *12* (4), 439–443. [DOI: 10.1007/BF02645964](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02645964).

If we could get some good insights on the Zn-Pt system, it will help us a lot and accelerate our research work. And if there isn't any paper regarding it, what will be the expert opinions?

Comment: Did you complement your search e.g., in [*SpringerMaterials*](https://materials.springer.com/), _specifically_ for the binary system [Pt-Zn](https://materials.springer.com/periodictable#Pt-Zn), there are 27 «element systems», including five entries about binary phase diagrams (e.g., 55-70 at% Zn, 573…1173 K; or 0-100 at% Zn, 273…1173 K).  You equally may work through for Gmelin (print stopped in the 1990s, now within Elsevier's Reaxys database).

Comment: Also, if you have access to the ASM Alloy Center it gathers references going way back. I’ll check my personal database…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few papers on Zinc-Platinum Systems (e.g., Ref.1 and 2, which are also sited in Ref.3), but most of them are in German. However, there were few useful data published by Johnson and Dillon in their Research and Development Report (Ref.4):

$$
\bf{The \ structures \ of \ platinum-zinc \ intermetallic \ phases}\\
\begin{array}{l|l r r}
\hline
\text{Compound*} & \text{Crystal Class} & \text{Lattice Parameters, }\pu{pm} & \text{References} \\
\hline
\ce{PtZn} & \text{Cubic} & a = 1811.6 & 2 \\
\ce{PtZn8} & - & - & 2 \\
\ce{PtZn2} (\xi) & \text{Hexagonal} & a = 410, \ c = 274 & 2 \\
\ce{PtZn}\ (\nu) & \text{Tetragonal} & a = 403, \ c = 347 & 1 \ \& \ 2 \\
\ce{Pt3Zn} & \text{Cubic} & a = 389 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\text{*All phases have a range of composition.}$$

Nowotny *et al.* (Ref.2) determined the solubility of platinum in liquid zinc by thermal analysis. Their measurements cover the range of $\pu{688-869 ^\circ C}$ and are shown in following Table:

$$
\begin{array}{l r r r}
\hline
T, \ \pu{^\circ C} & \frac{1000}{T}, \ \pu{K-1}  & \ce{Pt}, \ \text{weigh percent} & \ce{Pt}, \ \text{atom percent} \\
\hline
869 & 0.876 & 30.1 & 12.6 \\
825 & 0.911 & 23.2 & 9.2 \\
762 & 0.966 & 18.1 & 6.9 \\
728 & 0.999 & 14.8 & 5.5 \\
688 & 1.0404 & 9.8 & 3.5 \\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\text{*All phases have a range of composition.}$$

The direct measurements may be represented by the following empirical equations over the range of $\pu{675-875 ^\circ C}$ (Ref.4):

$$\log \left(a/o \ \ce{Pt}\right) = 3.881 - 3176T^{-1} \tag1$$
$$\log \left(w/o \ \ce{Pt}\right) = 3.917 - 2780T^{-1} \tag1$$
where $\left(a/o \ \ce{Pt}\right)$ is the atom percent platinum and $\left(w/o \ \ce{Pt}\right)$ is the weight percent platinum.

---

**References:**

1. H. Nowotny, E. Bauer, and A. Stempfl, “Die Kristallstrukturen von PtZn, PtCd und PdCd (English Translation: Crystal Structures of PtZn, PtCd, and PdCd),” *Monatshefte für Chemie* **1950**, *81(7)*, 1164-1164 (In German; DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00899370).
2. H. Nowotny, E. Bauer, A. Stempfl, and H. Bittner, “Über die Systeme: Platin-Zink und Platin-Kadmium (English Translation: On the System: Platinum-Zinc and Platinum-Cadmium),” *Monatshefte für Chemie* **1952**, *83(1)*, 221–236 (In German; DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00897822).
3. Z. Moser, “The Pt-Zn (Platinum-Zinc) system,” *Journal of Phase Equilibria* **1991**, *12*, 439–443 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02645964).
4. Irving Johnson and Ira G. Dillon, “The Solubility of Metals in Liquid Zinc,” USAEC Research and Development Report (Argonne National Laboratory, Argonne, IL), ANL-7083, pp. 78–79 (1965).

Comment: The ASM Alloy Phase Diagram center shows your (2) and (3), and further lists Y. Khan et al., J. Less-Common Met. 21(3) p. 293 (1970). It focuses on the brass-like phases between 55 and 70 at.% Zn.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I am grateful to you all. And a special thanks to Mr. Mathew Mahindaratne sir.